# Android Studio designer ( Rendering)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, rendering

I'm a beginner at android studio (v1.5.1).
My project has been built successfully but I have a problem in the designer.

> Rendering Problems
>   Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for
>   this layout?
> use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a
>   different layout, or fix the theme style references.

Note: I tried a different theme...

[image]

Comment: Try clicking `Automatically add all missing attributes`

Comment: It's not working for me

Comment: Just show the content of `build.gradle` file.

Comment: try reducing your api level at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the preview pane of right side reduce your API level to some lower API it will most probably solve your issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio (or IntelliJ IDEA),

If everything looks OK in your project and you're still receiving the error in your layouts, try to 'Invalidate caches & restart'.

Enjoy a coffee while Android Studio is recreating caches & indexes.

how to invalidate cache & restart

[image]